# $\sum_i^Ne^{(-(2i+1)^2a)}$ where a is is a positive real number

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for the summation of

$\sum_{i=0}^Ne^{(-(2i+1)^2a)}$.

The series converges to zero very fast, so even though ratio test is not conclusive, there must be some value where the sum converges to.

Comment: For finite $N$ there won't be a closed form. For $N=\infty$ you're involving theta functions.

Comment: @runway44 Can you check my answer? I verified it in python but it still needs an extra pair of eyes. Thank you!

Comment: Looks fine. ${}$

Comment: @runway44 Thanks for pointing me to the theta functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closed form expression can be reached using theta functions as u/runway44 suggested for $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Jacobi theta function is defined as

$\vartheta(q;z)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n^2}\cos(2\pi{n}z)$.

Equating $z=0$ equates the second term to 1. For $q=\exp(-a)$, we obtain

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \exp(-ai^2)=(\frac{\vartheta(q;0)-1}{2})$

Similarly, for $q=\exp(-4*a)$, $(\frac{\vartheta(q;0)-1}{2})$ gives summation over even numbers.

Hence,

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \exp(-a(2i+1)^2)=[\vartheta(\exp(-a);0)-\vartheta(\exp(-4a);0)]/2$