# $\sum_i^{\infty}e^{(-(2i+1)^2a)}(2i+1)^2$ where a is is a positive real number

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, theta-functions

I have asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661717/sum-ine-2i12a-where-a-is-is-a-positive-real-number) two days ago. One helpful person in the comments directed me to the Jacobi Theta functions and I was able to solve the rest myself. Starting from that point, I have:

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}q^{(2i+1)^2}=1+[\vartheta(q;0)-\vartheta(q^4;0)]/2$,

where $q=\exp(-a)$ Then,

$q\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}q^{(2i+1)^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}q^{(2i+1)^2}(2i+1)^2$.

So I only need to take the partial derivative of the first equation to find the result. Doing so gives me

$q\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}q^{(2i+1)^2}=\frac{q}{2}[\frac{\partial\vartheta(q;0)}{\partial q}-\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\vartheta(q^4;0)]$

$q\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}q^{(2i+1)^2}=\frac{q}{2}[\frac{\partial\vartheta(q;0)}{\partial q}-\frac{\partial\vartheta(q^4;0)}{\partial q}(4q^3)]$

Finally, using the relation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364762/implementation-of-derivatives-of-jacobi-theta-function), for python implementation, the last result is

$q\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}q^{(2i+1)^2}=\frac{q}{2}[-\frac{\partial^2\vartheta(q;0)}{(4q)\partial z^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vartheta(q^4;0)}{(4q)\partial z^2}(4q^3)]$.

However, while I verified the initial equation in python, I can't verify this final result.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I would be very happy if someone helps me with using align environment here. I tried a lot but failed.

Comment: Your calculation is overall not incorrect I'm sure you can find the typo/mistake yourself

Comment: @reuns Is there a small mistake in one of the steps?